# Unique solvability of weak Poisson equation with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, poissons-equation

I'm studying a Poisson BVP: Find $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ such that
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = F(v) \quad \forall v \in W^{1,p'}(\Omega),
$$
where $p$ and $p'$ are Hölder conjugates and $F$ belongs to the dual of $W^{1,p'}(\Omega)$. Note the implicit homogeneous Neumann boundary condition $\partial u / \partial \nu = 0$; consider solutions defined up to an additive constant.

My question: If a solution exists, is it unique (up to an additive constant)? I know that the answer is yes when $p=2$ due to coercivity but what about when, say, $p \in (1,2)$? This boils down to whether
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla w \cdot \nabla v = 0 \quad \forall v \in W^{1,p'}(\Omega)
$$
implies $w$ is constant, but I'm having difficulty showing that.

Comment: Idea: Is such a solution (to the homogeneous problem) automatically more regular (i.e. $W^{1,2}$)? If a portion of the boundary is flat, then $w$ is automatically smooth up to (that portion of) the boundary. However, I run into issues when dealing with non-flat boundary. Have you had any progress on this since you posted?

Comment: I was able to show uniqueness for convex polygonal domains, which is enough for my purposes for now. It turned out to be pretty simple by considering a dual problem where the source term is $w$ above ($w$ is also adjusted to have zero mean value). The solution of the dual problem belongs to $H^2$ and by Sobolev imbeddings qualifies as a test function. Then it's just integration by parts to show that $w=0$ in $L^2$ norm.